# Material property change via code doesn't show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

I'm using Unity 2020.3.3f1 (HDRP)
I have a prefab (cube) which has a emissive material on it.
After pressing the mouse button, I want it to increase its Emission intensity by 10.

Problem that I encountered:
The Inspector shows me that the Intensity is infact changing but the Game does not represent these changes (this means it's not getting "brighter" even though the material property says it does).

Now when I increase the amount via the Inspector manually, just by 0.1 even, all of the sudden the changes are now visible.

I think I tried everything now without luck...

How the code looks like in a nutshell:

```
public Material cubeMaterial;
private float intensity = 10;

if("mouseClick"){
intensity += 100;
cubeMaterial.setFloat("_EmissiveIntensity", intensity);
}
```

Comment: If you access the material with xxx.material, a new material will be created which is no longer referenced to the material on other renderers.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to modify only this gameObject's material, I recommand you to use `MaterialPropertyBlock` to modify a property of your material.

If you don't, a new material will be created behind the scene and can lead to memory problems.

To do this, get a reference to the gameObject's renderer, get its property block, modify it and reassign the modified property block.

You can learn more on this [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

Hope that helped ;)

Comment: Good hint, I will read up on this topic :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the default HDRP/Lit shader for your material. If that's so, you can access your cube emission intensity via "_EmissiveColor" shader keyword like this:

`cubeMaterial.GetColor("_EmissiveColor");`

which returns a Color value.

And you can modify it in a similar way:

`cubeMaterial.SetColor("_EmissiveColor", startingEmission * 1.1f);`

In general, when working with HDRP material shaders it's always safe to look up the shader keywords, you can do it via navigating to your material in the inspector, clicking the kogwheel and selecting edit shader, which opens the .shader file.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. With your input, I found a solution.
But to clarify for others: `cubeMaterial.GetColor("_EmissiveColor");` returns a RGBA Value.

To change it, we can't modify it like quoted above, but we can simply create a color:
`Color test = new Color(intensity, intensity, intensity, intensity);` and use SetCoior on the GameObject.
This worked! :)
Allthough I still think it's weird Unity behaviour, that editing "_EmissiveIntensity" doesn't work...

Comment: Oops, my bad, don't know why I said that it returns a float value, brainlag, but anyway, glad it helped!